# Google Compute Engine Server Location Latency Suggests Different Zone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

During an inquiry into long time to first byte times I used the service at keycdn to test my server performance from different locations. I'm based in the UK and my instance & disk are based in the Netherlands or europe-west4-a. Below is the result and you can also repeat the test using the URL provided.

My questions are why is it so much faster from the US when I set it up with the aim to be faster in the UK & what can I do to get that kind of TTFB for my UK visitors?

https://tools.keycdn.com/performance?url=https://doggywoggywoowoo.com/product/mix-n-match-3-for-20-with-free-next-day-delivery/

[image: Key CDN Results]

Edited to add a fresh test done today, with completely different results. Results appear as expected, still unsure as to why the previous results were the way they were.

[image: Fresh Test Run]

Comment: A similar service is saying that the performance is best from Europe - https://performance.sucuri.net/domain/doggywoggywoowoo.com.  I'm not that familiar with either of these performance testing sites but you might want to try a few.  You can also measure this from your computer using Chrome -> Developer Tools -> Network.  Good luck.

Comment: Please note the results may vary depending upon the source and the path between source and destination (network hops) as I tested your third-party link provided and I got different result.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that doggywoggywoowoo.com is using Cloudflare. This means that the end user is actually talking to a proxy server near to them, which is in turn talking to your servers in Europe. DNS, Connect and TLS times are fairly constant as the only measure talking to that proxy. TTFB can still vary as that does include getting the response from the server in Europe.

The TTFB in your screenshot is in the 1-10 second range. However America to UK round trip times are in the 800-200ms range. So it looks like your TTFB likely is caused by delays *other* than the network latency.

Comment: I don;t think this is the case based on a repeat of the test I did today. Perhaps it's something to do with how Google routes traffic? New screenshot added to the original post.